# I got TypeError: getMboSet(): expected 2-4 args; got 1 in <script> while using MAXIMO Automation Script

Tags: automation, jython, maximo

I'm developing an automation script and I'm getting the next error:

**BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the BAX_ISSUEGL script for the BAX_ISSUEGL launch point from running.
TypeError: getMboSet(): expected 2-4 args; got 1 in  at line number 5 More information**

I'm using jython 2.5.2, MAXIMO 7.6.0.9. The automation is an Object Launch Point automation.

Someone knows why I'm getting the error?

The automation script:

```
from psdi.mbo import Mbo
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants

#Get object
issueCI = Mbo.getMboSet("ISSUECURRENTITEM")

#Get Storeloc and Accounts
storeloc=issueCI.getString("STORELOC");
debitacct=issueCI.getString("GLDEBITACCT");

if debitacct[0:4] != storeloc:
 errorgroup= "Credit Error";
 errorkey= "CreditError";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with line 5 is that you have capitalized `Mbo` -- suggesting you're referring to the class `psdi.mbo.Mbo` that you imported. But the launch point will pass an implicit variable called `mbo` to your script, and `mbo` will be an instance of (a subclass of) `Mbo`.

Python methods are functions in classes, and they take `self` as the first parameter. So, in `mbo.getMboSet("RELATIONSHIPNAME")`, Python is going to internally convert that `getMboSet(mbo, "RELATIONSHIPNAME")`. By referencing the class instead of an instance of the class, you were actually leaving out that `self` parameter. And this is why you were told that `getMboSet()` was expecting "2-4 arguments" when the JavaDocs for `Mbo.getMboSet()` show overloads of that method that take 1, 2 or 3 arguments.

FYI: For the code you pasted, once you change `Mbo` to `mbo` on line 5, you don't need any of your `from ... import` lines. You only need those if you directly reference the classes, like line 5 was doing in error.